# Initramdisk init script - catch invalid kernel driver load

Tags: linux, initrd

Recently I added new drivers to my `initrd` image, to be able to run under VMware and Hyper-v platform as well.

My question is, how can I catch failure during driver loading? If `insmod` fails while `hv_vmbus` insertion I want to skip 5 additional drivers from loading (to get rid of "Unknown symbols xyz").

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: formatting, include screenshot